# log4j.xml configuration is not storing logs to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following log4j.xml configuration file, but don't see the log data stored in the file specified (in my documents folder: `Documents/debug.log`).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
   debug="true">

   <appender name="applicationLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
      <param name="File" value="Documents/debug.log" />
      <param name="threshold" value="TRACE" />
      <param name="MaxNumberOfDays" value="90"/>
      <param name="CompressBackups" value="TRUE"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
  
   <logger name="APP_VERSION_LOGGER">
      <appender-ref ref="applicationVersionFile" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.springframework">
      <level value="WARN" />
   </logger>
  
   <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="applicationLogFile" />
      <appender-ref ref="bmcAlertFile" />
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

How an I get my log data sent to my `Documents` directory on my computer? I'm using `log4j-core` version `2.13.3`. And yes, I've looke at the docs, but I still don't see where my log data is going.

Comment: Are you using log4j1.x or log4j2? Your use log4j2's lib without log4j1.x bridge (log4j-1.2.api), and log4j1.x's config. It's certainly not going to work. Make sure your log4j version is consistent with log4j config and your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Your line here says:

```
<param name="File" value="Documents/debug.log" />
```

It will make a folder with name `Documents` on your project root level and logs will be there.

I f you want to put them in to specific location on your machine then you need to provide full pathname.
ex.

```
<param name="File" value="/Users/myUser/Documents/debug.log" />
```